# How to continue a seeded RSpec run?

Tags: rspec

Is there a way to restart a seeded [RSpec](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/command-line) run from a particular point, rather than from the beginning?

When making a change that potentially affects all files (e.g., [removing `Bundler.require`](http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2012/12/5-reasons-to-avoid-bundler-require)) in a large code-base, I want to run a full set of RSpec tests, fix the first error, then re-run the tests with the same seed.

```
$ cd myproj
$ rspec --seed=0 --fail-fast

...

Finished in 9 minutes 59 seconds (files took 12.09 seconds to load)
9999 examples, 1 failure, 0 pending

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/my_class_spec.rb:22 # MyClass #my_method

Randomized with seed 0
```

At this point I realize that `my_class.rb` is missing a `require`.  I fix it but I'd rather not run the preceeding 9998 passing examples again.

I'd love to be able to specify a start point, something like this:

```
$ rspec --seed=0 --from='./spec/my_class_spec.rb:22' --fail-fast
```

Or, if rspec is can determine the last failure, something like this would be even better:

```
$ rspec --seed=0 --continue --fail-fast
```

Obviously running with a seed is not good practice in general since tests should not be order dependent, but it does allow repeatability which is what I'm looking for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RSpec does not support a `--continue` flag.  It would have to persist some state between runs about how far the last run got in the whole suite.  It doesn't do this (and we have no plans to do so) but it would be pretty easy for someone to write an extension that does this.

That said, the soon-to-be-released RSpec 3.3 includes a new feature that supports a similar but slightly different workflow: `--next-failure`:

https://relishapp.com/rspec-staging/rspec-core/docs/command-line/only-failures

With `--next-failure`, here's how you'd achieve a workflow similar to what you're asking for:

1. Run `rspec` to run the entire suite.  It'll record the `last_run_status` of all the executed examples so that it knows which failed.
2. Repeatedly run `rspec --next-failure` (or `rspec --next-failure --seed 0` if you want to force a particular random ordering rather than using defined order).  RSpec will filter what is run to just the examples that failed the last time they ran, and will abort as soon as one fails.

By repeatedly running `rspec` with `--next-failure` you can work through each of the failures individually without paying the cost of running the whole suite.

Note that to use this new feature, you first have to configure `example_status_persistence_file_path` so RSpec knows where to persist the last run status of each example.

Comment: The `--next-failure` feature will be perfect.  I'm really looking forward to 3.3!  One suggestion: instead of `example_status_persistence_file_path`, how about a command-line option `--persist-status` (which uses a default/recommended/conventional path) and `--persist-status=my/custom/path` that allows customization.

Comment: Originally we were going to provide a default for the file path (and I was strongly in favor of it) but ran into issues figuring out the right user experience when we can't write to it (since we have no guarantee we'll be able to write to _any_ file path we choose as a default).  You can read the conversation at https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/pull/1888 if you want to know the details.